# How to calculate % difference between matrix columns and add to values matrix as it iterates

Tags: r, loops

I have a matrix of week to week sales (columns) for several stores (rows). the goal is to calculate the percentage difference between the weeks and highlight values that are abnormal, for example, a 70 - 100% increase/decrease in sales. I'm having trouble with looping logic and properly accessing the elements of the matrix.

So far I've set up a loop that calculates the difference of one row and but it repeats that row 16 times instead of going to the next row in the matrix. Also, I added a conditional statement to highlight the values w/condformat but I don't believe that I'm using it correctly.

```
library(condformat)

#Specifies location of cvs file  
dat <- read.csv("S:/Brooke Hughes/APT Store Level Data 5_28 .csv")

# Prints Table values
dat

# Checks class of data set
class(dat)

# Converts dataframe into matrix
mat <- as.matrix(dat)

class(mat)
condformat(mat)

# Sets column number to begin iterations 
for (col(mat) in colnames(mat)) {
  s1 <- col(mat)
  s2 <- col(mat) + 1
  #calculates percentage increase for two dates   
  percdiff <- ((s2-s1)/s1)

  print(percdiff)


  # Colors in cells of weeks with sales abnormalities 
  if (percdiff > .8 ){
    rule_text_color(s1, na.color= "#7D00FF")  
    rule_text_color(s2, na.color= "#7D00FF") 
  }


}
```

I expect the output to show the original matrix with a column of the percentage difference calculation between the two column values used to obtain it. Then on the column with the percentage difference, I want the values to be highlighted if they are over a certain threshold.

So far I have this

```
  [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4] [,5]      [,6]      [,7]  [,8]      [,9] [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]      [,14]      [,15]
[1,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.125 0.1111111   0.1 0.09090909 0.08333333 0.07692308 0.07142857 0.06666667
[2,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.125 0.1111111   0.1 0.09090909 0.08333333 0.07692308 0.07142857 0.06666667
[3,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.125 0.1111111   0.1 0.09090909 0.08333333 0.07692308 0.07142857 0.06666667
[4,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.125 0.1111111   0.1 0.09090909 0.08333333 0.07692308 0.07142857 0.06666667
[5,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25  0.2 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.125 0.1111111   0.1 0.09090909 0.08333333 0.07692308 0.07142857 0.06666667
```